# Spiking Neural Network: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, neural-network, google-colaboratory

I'm writing a Spiking Neural Network to monitor the structural health of a building.
The dataset I have is a (129, 5651) Matrix containing the firing times of the network, divided in (129, 3957) training set and a (129, 1694) test set.

This is the Matrix of the firing times (129, 5651):

```
[[ 2.6 2.5 2.6 ... 2.8 2.7 2.5] 
 [ 2.7 2.6 2.6 ... 2.8 2.8 2.6] 
 [ 5. 4.6 5. ... 6.4 6.1 5. ] 
            ... 
 [ 0. 0. 0. ... 18.9 18.6 0. ] 
 [ 0. 0. 0. ... 0. 18. 0. ] 
 [ 0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0. ]]
```

This is instead the code I'm using as a reference, but I want to use my dataset instead of the MNIST one:
https://snntorch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/tutorial_5.html

Here I write all the code with my substitutions:

```
batch_size = 128
ok_train = np.array(Matrix[:,0:3446])
faulty_train = np.array(Matrix[:, 4923:5434])
train_loader= np.concatenate((ok_train,faulty_train), axis=1);

ok_test = np.array(Matrix[:, 3446:4923])
faulty_test = np.array(Matrix[:, 5434:5651])
test_loader = np.concatenate((ok_test,faulty_test), axis=1);

# Leaky neuron model, overriding the backward pass with a custom function
class LeakySurrogate(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, beta, threshold=1.0):
      super(LeakySurrogate, self).__init__()

      # initialize decay rate beta and threshold
      self.beta = beta
      self.threshold = threshold
      self.spike_op = self.SpikeOperator.apply

  # the forward function is called each time we call Leaky
  def forward(self, input_, mem):
    spk = self.spike_op((mem-self.threshold))  # call the Heaviside function
    reset = (spk * self.threshold).detach()  # removes spike_op gradient from reset
    mem = self.beta * mem + input_ - reset  # Eq (1)
    return spk, mem

  # Forward pass: Heaviside function
  # Backward pass: Override Dirac Delta with the Spike itself
  @staticmethod
  class SpikeOperator(torch.autograd.Function):
      @staticmethod
      def forward(ctx, mem):
          spk = (mem > 0).float() # Heaviside on the forward pass: Eq(2)
          ctx.save_for_backward(spk)  # store the spike for use in the backward pass
          return spk

      @staticmethod
      def backward(ctx, grad_output):
          (spk,) = ctx.saved_tensors  # retrieve the spike
          grad = grad_output * spk # scale the gradient by the spike: 1/0
          return grad
```

```
lif1 = LeakySurrogate(beta=0.9)

batch_size = 128

dtype = torch.float
device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")

# Network Architecture
num_inputs = 129
num_hidden = 1000
num_outputs = 2

# Temporal Dynamics
num_steps = 25
beta = 0.95
```

```
# Define Network
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Initialize layers
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(num_inputs, num_hidden)
        self.lif1 = snn.Leaky(beta=beta)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(num_hidden, num_outputs)
        self.lif2 = snn.Leaky(beta=beta)

    def forward(self, x):

        # Initialize hidden states at t=0
        mem1 = self.lif1.init_leaky()
        mem2 = self.lif2.init_leaky()

        # Record the final layer
        spk2_rec = []
        mem2_rec = []

        for step in range(num_steps):
            cur1 = self.fc1(x)
            spk1, mem1 = self.lif1(cur1, mem1)
            cur2 = self.fc2(spk1)
            spk2, mem2 = self.lif2(cur2, mem2)
            spk2_rec.append(spk2)
            mem2_rec.append(mem2)

        return torch.stack(spk2_rec, dim=0), torch.stack(mem2_rec, dim=0)

# Load the network onto CUDA if available
net = Net().to(device)
```

```
# pass data into the network, sum the spikes over time
# and compare the neuron with the highest number of spikes
# with the target

def print_batch_accuracy(data, targets, train=False):
    output, _ = net(data.view(batch_size, -1))
    _, idx = output.sum(dim=0).max(1)
    acc = np.mean((targets == idx).detach().cpu().numpy())

    if train:
        print(f"Train set accuracy for a single minibatch: {acc*100:.2f}%")
    else:
        print(f"Test set accuracy for a single minibatch: {acc*100:.2f}%")

def train_printer():
    print(f"Epoch {epoch}, Iteration {iter_counter}")
    print(f"Train Set Loss: {loss_hist[counter]:.2f}")
    print(f"Test Set Loss: {test_loss_hist[counter]:.2f}")
    print_batch_accuracy(data, targets, train=True)
    print_batch_accuracy(test_data, test_targets, train=False)
    print("\n")

loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=5e-4, betas=(0.9, 0.999))
```

TRAINING

```
num_epochs = 1
loss_hist = []
test_loss_hist = []
counter = 0

# Outer training loop
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    iter_counter = 0
    train_batch = iter(train_loader)

    # Minibatch training loop
for data, targets in train_batch:
        data = data.to(device)
        targets = targets.to(device)

        # forward pass
        net.train()
        spk_rec, mem_rec = net(data.view(batch_size, -1))

        # initialize the loss & sum over time
        loss_val = torch.zeros((1), dtype=dtype, device=device)
        for step in range(num_steps):
            loss_val += loss(mem_rec[step], targets)

        # Gradient calculation + weight update
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss_val.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Store loss history for future plotting
        loss_hist.append(loss_val.item())

        # Test set
        with torch.no_grad():
            net.eval()
            test_data, test_targets = next(iter(test_loader))
            test_data = test_data.to(device)
            test_targets = test_targets.to(device)

            # Test set forward pass
            test_spk, test_mem = net(test_data.view(batch_size, -1))

            # Test set loss
            test_loss = torch.zeros((1), dtype=dtype, device=device)
            for step in range(num_steps):
                test_loss += loss(test_mem[step], test_targets)
            test_loss_hist.append(test_loss.item())

            # Print train/test loss/accuracy
            if counter % 50 == 0:
                train_printer()
            counter += 1
            iter_counter +=1
```

But I keep getting this error flag if I substitute the training/testing sets with mine: does anybody know how I can adapt such dataset to this Net?

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-9d1979c2b76f> in <module>
     10 
     11     # Minibatch training loop
---> 12 for data, targets in train_batch:
     13         data = data.to(device)
     14         targets = targets.to(device)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: What this means is each entry in `train_batch` has some length not equal to 2. Figure out how many it actually has and unpack those.

Comment: @tadman I figured that since I have a matrix (129,5651) I have to unpack 5651 values. But how can I modify this code and do such thing? This is not my code so I'm not fully understanding how it works

Comment: Well, `a,b = (list_of_5651_things)` is not going to happen. Which of those *would* you like? Remember you can always index, like `for batch in train_batch` and then `batch[0]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

This might fix your problem. As there are two variables for an iterator while unpacking, using 'enumerate' could return the count and its values [Python iterator unpacking - enumeration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate)

```
for data, targets in enumerate(train_batch):
    print(targets)
```